# Date from string yields different dates in different browsers

Tags: javascript, date, browser

```
var d = "2014-04-22";
var t = "00:00";
var o = new Date(d + "T" + t);
```

Firefox yields the correct date: `Tue Apr 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Chrome on the other hand yields: `Tue Apr 22 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

If I replace the `T` with a space, Chromes `o` contains the correct date but it's an `Invalid Date` in firefox.

How can I make both browsers use the correct date?

*edit:* `t = "00:00:00.000Z"` results in `Tue Apr 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` in both browsers, but that's the incorrect date.

*edit:* `t = "00:00:00.000+02:00"` results in correct times, but the timezone can't be automatically taken from the machine the browser runs on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Date.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) documentation and the docs for [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Chrome and Firefox do seem to deal with timezones differently.  In my testing, if you append an explicit timezone designator, they behave nicely.  Either "Z" (a special token for UTC) or `"+hh:mm"`, depending on what output you want.

If you want to have a more flexible date parser (which is useful for many other things), you can use some sort of library - either [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) or [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) will do that quite well.  Choosing which depends on personal preference and the details of what you're doing besides this.

*Edit: My original answer was wrong in that ISO8601 does accept just HH:MM, and Chrome and Firefox do have disparate behaviors for non-timezone-specified codes.*

Comment: The hours not being zero padded was an error in typing the code for my question. Adding the seconds (date string then being `00:00:00`) does not help.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're running into timezone issues.  The issues above still will cause issues, but I do still see timezone differences (Firefox translates to local time, Chrome to GMT)

Comment: Having "00:00:00.000Z" results in having the same time in both browsers, but that result being a time of `02:00` instead of `00:00`. Not it's indeed *only* a timezone issue...

Comment: I've edited my answer: you can also append "+02:00" (or whatever timezone you want) to the timestamp to specify a timezone.

Comment: So apparently timezone and summer/standardtime management isn't done automatically and has to be cared manually for?

Comment: Looks like that is the case, although you can use [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to determine time zones, and that does take summer/standard into consideration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now. This is the working portable solution I'll use: `"00:00:00.000"+ (n.getTimezoneOffset()<=0?"+":"-") + ("0"+(n.getTimezoneOffset()/ 60 * -1)).slice(-2)+":00";`

Comment: Indeed, that should work.  Not too messy, and does the job.  If things start getting much tricker, I'd recommend using one of the libraries I linked.  They add weight, but make things nicer to work with.